# authentication failed after postgreSQL maintenance on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Today I got an email saying my database requires maintenance, it did the maintenance and reported that everything is back up. However now whenever I try to access the db trough my website I get an error:

'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user...'

I can still access the db trough CLI but the credentials given for the database have stopped working. Using hobby dev so I cant even write a ticket... Any ideas how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable every time you connect? I suspect not.

Comment: @Chris I belive I am, it follows the format given in postgresql documentation

Comment: Try rotating the credentials, also make sure they didn't roll you into a different database, you might be trying to login to the old one when you might be on a new database

Comment: @ricks You are correct, it just took very long time for them to update my credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It just took over 12hours for my credentials to get changed, it works now.